# Having trouble displaying conditional formatting icons when comparing number of service orders month over month in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to apply a conditional formatting rule to a matrix that gives me:

- A green arrow when the value of the current month is BIGGER than the value of the last month;
- A yellow arrow when the value of the current month is EQUAL to the value of the last month;
- A red  arrow when the value of the current month is LOWER than the value of the last month.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVeA6.jpg

Do I need to use a table instead of a matrix and add each month's value individually as columns? My matrix works like a pivot table, so all the column values uses the same field.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first thing you need to do is calculate the Value of LM(Last Month) then calculate the difference between LM and Current Month

[image]

then in the Conditional Formatting do like this

[image]

and the final result should look like this

[image]